Solve the equation $x^3-3x=\frac{a^6+1}{a^3}$
Solve the equation $x^3-3x=\frac{a^6+1}{a^3}$, knowing that $a\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1,0,1\}$.
I thought of writing the equation as $a^6+1-x^3 a^3+3xa^3=(a^2+1)(a^4-a^2+1)+a^3(3x-x^3)=0$
I also tried uisng the Horner Theorem but got to nothing useful

It is just a cubic equation in $x$. Use the trigonometric or hyperbolic solution.

Since $\ \frac{a^6+1}{a^3}=2a\ $ for $\ a=\pm1\ ,$ the stated problem is equivalent to solving the simpler equation $\ x^3-3x=b\ ,$  with real $\ b\ne\pm2\ .$

Let $A=a+\frac{1}{a}$. Notice that $$x^3-3x=A^3-3A\tag{1}$$ so it is clear that $x=A$ satisfies $(1)$. We then have  $$x^3-3x-A^3+3A=(x-A)(x^2+Ax+A^2-3)$$ The quadratic polynomial has roots: $$x=\frac{-A\pm\sqrt{3}\sqrt{4-A^2}}{2}$$ where $A\neq \pm 2$.

To clarify, where did you use that $ A \neq \pm 2$? It's fine for the quadratic to have repeated roots.

@CalvinLin $a\neq\pm 1$

I'm asking if we even need that condition. Doesn't seem like we do. We have the double root $ x = -A/2 = \mp 1$ which works.

$\textbf{The strategic approach:}$
Our equation is $x^3 - 3x = a^3 + \frac{1}{a^3}$. Bringing the $3x$ over, we see
$$ x^3 = a^3 + 3x + \frac{1}{a^3} $$
The right side of the equation looks an awful lot like the result of the binomial theorem. Indeed, setting $x$ in a way in which the right side fits into the shape of the binomial theorem (i.e. $x = a + \frac{1}{a}$), we see that the equation is satisfied:
$$ (a + \frac1a)^3 = a^3 + 3a + \frac3a + \frac1{a^3} $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow (a + \frac1a)^3 = \binom{3}{0}a^3 + \binom{3}{1}a + \binom{3}{2}\frac1a + \binom{3}{3}\frac1{a^3} $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow (a + \frac1a)^3 = (a + \frac1a)^3 $$
$\textbf{The brute force approach:}$
Let $b := \frac{a^6 + 1}{a^3}$. We now have an equation of the form
$$ x^3 - 3x - b = 0 $$
This is a depressed cubic. Generally, depressed cubics of the form
$x^3 + px - q$ can be solved by setting
$$ (i) 3st = p $$
$$ (ii) s^3 - t^3 = q $$
(then $s - t$ is a root of the cubic, factoring out turns it into a quadratic, so the other 2 roots can be found easily).
In our case, we'd find
$$ (i) 3st = -3 \implies st = -1 \implies s = -\frac{1}{t} $$
Plugging into the second equation:
$$ -\frac{1}{t^3} - t^3 = b $$
$$ \implies -1 - t^6 =bt^3 $$
$$ \implies t^6 + bt^3 + 1 = 0 $$
Now, substituting $v = t^3$, we find
$$ v^2 + bv + 1 = 0 $$
$$ \implies v = -\frac{b}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{b^2}{4} - 1} $$
Now, note that $v = t^3 \implies t = \sqrt[3]{v}$ so in total
$$ t = \sqrt[3]{v} = \sqrt[3]{-\frac{b}{2}  \pm \sqrt{\frac{b^2}{4} - 1}}$$
Trying to simplify the expression, we'll plug back in $b = \frac{a^6 + 1}{a^3}$. So:
$$ t = \sqrt[3]{-\frac{a^6 + 1}{2a^3} \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} \frac{a^{12} + 2a^6 + 1}{a^6} - 1}}$$
$$ = \sqrt[3]{-\frac{a^6 + 1}{2a^3} \pm \sqrt{\frac{a^6}{4} - \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4a^6}}} $$
$$ = \sqrt[3]{-\frac{a^6 + 1}{2a^3} \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{a^6 -2+\frac{1}{a^6}}} $$
$$ = \sqrt[3]{-\frac{a^6 + 1}{2a^3} \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(a^3 - \frac{1}{a^3})^2}} $$
$$ = \sqrt[3]{-\frac{a^6 + 1}{2a^3} \pm \frac{1}{2} (a^3 - \frac{1}{a^3})} $$
$$ = \sqrt[3]{\frac{-a^6 - 1 \pm(a^6 - 1)}{2a^3}}$$
At this point, there's 2 potential solutions. We'll choose the one with a plus for now:
$$ = \sqrt[3]{\frac{-a^6 - 1 + a^6 - 1}{2a^3}}$$
$$ = \sqrt[3]{\frac{-2}{2a^3}}$$
$$ = -\frac{1}{a}$$
Thus, $t = -\frac{1}{a}$. Thus $s = a$. Thus a root of the polynomial is
$$ s - t = a + \frac{1}{a} $$
Plugging back into the equation to check our result:
$$ x^3 - 3x = \frac{a^6 + 1}{a^3} $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow (a + \frac{1}{a})^3 - 3a - \frac3a = a^3 + \frac{1}{a^3} $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow (a + \frac{1}{a})^3 = a^3 + 3a + \frac3a + \frac1{a^3}$$
Using the binomial theorem, we see that this equality is true.
Having found 1 root of the polynomial, the others are easily identifiable by factoring out the root we already have and solving the resulting quadratic equation.
